# c++ continue versus break

Tags: c++, break, continue

Which statement will be executed after "continue" or "break" ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
 {
     // statement1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     for(int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
     {
         //statement2                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         if(someTest)
             continue;
     }
     //statement3                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 }

for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
 {   
     // statement1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     for(int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
     {   
         //statement2                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         if(someTest)
             break;
     }
     //statement3                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 }
```

Comment: Couldn't you figure it out by simple debugging/tracing?

Comment: It is easy to check. Have you any compiler?

Comment: ah that's right.. just sometimes, grabbing concept is better than testing

Comment: This smells like homework... and if not, you should still go back to basics, find a nice book or tutorial and read. This is a really basic question that is solved in *all* tutorials.

Comment: it wasn't homework, maybe my book was not that good. :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

continue: `++j` and then if `j < count` then `statement2` otherwise `statement3`

break: `statement3`

Comment: For the first case: not exactly. After ++j, the loop test (j < count) will be carried out and if true, then statement2.

Answer (score 22):

Continue jumps straight to the top of the innermost loop, where the per-iteration code and continuance check will be carried out (sections 3 and 2 of the `for` loop).

Break jumps straight to immediately after the innermost loop without changing anything.

It may be easier to think of the former jumping to the closing brace of the innermost loop while the latter jumps just beyond it.

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for not actually answering the question, in that "continue jumps... incrementing the counter", but this doesn't describe the next step - retesting the condition, and that that determines whether statement 2 or 3 executes.  It might seem too obvious to spell out, but then when there's a question about break and continue these things can't be taken for granted. :-/.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for the edit. It added quite a bit of clarity.

Answer (score 11):

`continue` ends the current iteration, virtually it is the same as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
 {
     // statement1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     for(int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
     {
         //statement2                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         if(someTest)
             goto end_of_loop;
end_of_loop:
     }
     //statement3                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 }
```

`break` exits the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
 {   
     // statement1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     for(int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
     {   
         //statement2                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         if(someTest)
             goto after_loop;
     }
after_loop:
     //statement3                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 }
```

Comment: +1 A potentially easy-to-follow way to explain it, but would have been even clearer if there was some code in the loop after the test (I know - not your fault, just the way the question was).

Answer (score 2):

**`Continue`**: It depends.  The continue statement will execute the 'increment' part of the for-loop, then the 'test' part, and then decide whether to execute the next iteration or leave the loop.
So it could be statement 2 or 3.

**`Break`**: statement 3.

Btw, is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

statement2 will execute after the continue, given that the loop was not in the last iteration.

statement3 will execute after the break.

'continue' (as the name suggests) continues the loop, while skipping the rest of the statements in the current iteration.

'break' breaks and exits from the loop.

Answer (score -1):

1. For continue, innerloop is executed with new i,j values of i,j+1
2. For break, innerloop is executed with new i,j values of i+1,0

ofcourse if boundary conditions are satisfied