# How to jump from loop in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I read all app package from my device and set to some class. I want to jump from loop when a specified package comes like "com.example.abc".How can I do that

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    boolean exit=false;
    int currentIndex=0;

    try
    {
        PackageInfo pi=null;
        int scannedApps=0;
        int menacesFound=0;

        while(running && currentIndex<_packagesToScan.size())
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);

            if(!_isPaused)
            {

                pi = _packagesToScan.get(currentIndex);

                dtp.scannedFiles = currentIndex;
                dtp.appName = pi.packageName;
                dtp.icon = StaticTools.getIconFromPackage(dtp.appName, _activity);
                dtp.totalFiles = _packagesToScan.size();

                boolean b = isPackageInMenacesSet(dtp.appName);
                if (b)
                    dtp.foundMenaces++;

                publishProgress(dtp);

                ++scannedApps;
                ++currentIndex;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex)
    {
        Log.w("APP", "Scanning task was interrupted");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Use break; when your package is found to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

use "break"

```
while(true)
{ 
   if(condition)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **break;** when your package is found to get out of the loop.

If you want to enter into next iteration of the loop without getting out of it then use **continue;** command. For more information about break and continue check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368141/c-continue-versus-break).