# User Input/If Statement keeping returning instead of continuing

Tags: c++, if-statement, user-input

I am trying to run this code and when I enter the user input of "nfc123" it prints Door Unlocked although then It returns to the start and wants me to Unlock the Door again. I would like it to continue and ask me if I would like to Lock the Door.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main( int, char ** )
{
    std::string input;

    while( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Unlock Door Code: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input;
        if( input == "nfc123" )
        {
            std::cout << "Door Unlocked" << std::endl;
            continue;

        }
        else if( input == "end" )
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Wrong Code: " << input << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::string input2;

    while( true )
    {

        std::cout << "Lock Door Code: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input2;
        if( input2 == "nfc123" )
        {
            std::cout << "Door Locked" << std::endl;

        }
        else if( input2 == "end" )
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Wrong Code: " << input2 << std::endl;
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `break` instead of `continue`? Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368141/c-continue-versus-break

Comment: Well, that was simple, thank you. Do you also have an Idea on how to return to the top after I have locked the door?  break, continue and return just go back to the lock door sequence.

Comment: You can use a `goto` with a label or you can wrap the whole thing in another loop

Comment: Oh yeah, cool thank you.